# Make a group of element move horizontally to the left

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I have arranged a few divs to align horizontally. I want to create 3 rows and in each row, I want divs to move horizontally to the left at varying speeds.

Check this giphy for visual reference : http://www.giphy.com/gifs/ME8Av6LT9hgymDnqSP

```css
.roundeddivs {
  background: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  border-radius: 44px;
  max-height: "1px";
  width: auto;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 3px 0px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
}


.block {
  padding: 6rem 2rem;
}

.arrangeflex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="block  ">
<div class="arrangeflex">
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 1</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 2</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 3</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 4</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 5</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 6</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 7</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 8</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 9</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 10</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 11</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 12</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 13</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 14</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 15</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 16</span>
<span class="roundeddivs">Hello 17</span>
</div>
</section>
```

[image]

Animated like this ([animated GIF)](https://media3.giphy.com/media/ME8Av6LT9hgymDnqSP/giphy.gif?cid=790b761124aee8cb497433a465102821f816dc2752a1b712&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g):

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I want divs to move horizontally to the left at varying speeds."? As in, you want this to be animated? If so, then we need more detail because you haven't described how the animation should work at all, such as where the elements would originate from and where they would end up, or how it should loop or repeat, etc. If you're not describing an animation then "varying speeds" is the wrong language (do you mean "varying offsets" perhaps?)

Comment: Also you say you want the elements arranged into rows and columns - if so then don't use `display: flex;` (even with `flex: wrap;`) because `display: flex;` gives you almost zero control over aligning items in different rows - you should use `display: grid;` with auto-tracks instead.

Comment: @Dai I'm looking to make something like this : http://www.giphy.com/gifs/ME8Av6LT9hgymDnqSP .

Comment: You can't use a single `flex` element with `flex-wrap` for that because each row has to be controlled separately.

Comment: BTW, your posted HTML is invalid: your `<div class="arrangeflex">`  is missing its closing tag  - and you should remove the excess whitespace from `<div class="block  ">`.

Comment: Yeah. I missed it while copying and pasting the HTML element.

Comment: How much control do you have over the HTML? Can you group the `<span>` elements into rows yourself or do you want it to be automatic? If so, then _on what basis_ should the browser's layout-engine decide which `<span>` elements go into each row?

Comment: @Dai I can control the HTML element. So I group the <span> elements into rows myself. So I can define row 1, row 2 and row 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can add copies of the elements to your HTML you can do the rest in CSS.

Each row is treated independently and has at least two copies of the items in that row - put in more (doubling up) if you think the items wont stretch across the full width of the containing block on some devices.

A row moves 50% of its total width to the left, then starts again. This means the action looks smooth as the second half of the row is "overwritten by" the first half when it hits the left hand side of its container.

This snippet uses a CSS variable --t to set the timing, and each of the rows can set its own --t.

Just a couple of rows shown in this snippet to give the idea. Add more as required, each within its own parent div. I've put 4 copies of the items in each row - probably overkill, it depends on your content and what devices you are trying to style for.

```css
.roundeddivs {
  background: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  border-radius: 44px;
  max-height: "1px";
  width: auto;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 3px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
}

.block {
  padding: 6rem 2rem;
  width: 50vw;
}

.marquees {
  margin: 0 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquees>* {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  animation: move var(--d) linear infinite;
}

.marquees>*:nth-child(1) {
  --d: 9s;
}

.marquees>*:nth-child(2) {
  --d: 15s;
}

.marquees>*:nth-child(3) {
  --d: 8s;
}

.marquees>*:nth-child(4) {
  --d: 15ss;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="block  ">
    <div class="marquees">
      <div>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 1</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 2</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 3</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 4</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 5</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 6</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 7</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 8</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 1</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 2</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 3</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 4</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 5</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 6</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 7</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 8</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 1</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 2</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 3</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 4</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 5</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 6</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 7</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 8</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 1</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 2</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 3</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 4</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 5</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 6</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 7</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 8</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 9</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 10</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 11</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 12</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 13</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 14</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 15</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 16</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 17</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 9</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 10</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 11</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 12</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 13</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 14</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 15</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 16</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 17</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 9</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 10</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 11</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 12</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 13</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 14</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 15</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 16</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 17</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 9</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 10</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 11</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 12</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 13</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 14</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 15</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 16</span>
        <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 17</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Obviously you will want to play with the timings to get the effect you need.

Comment: I like this approach

Comment: This is magic. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is to use a marquee tag , however the element wont show up from the right directly .

```css
.marquee{
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<section>

<div class="block  ">
<div class="arrangeflex">

<marquee scrollamount="6">
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 1</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 2</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 3</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 4</span>
</marquee>

<marquee scrollamount="5">
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 5</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 6</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 7</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 8</span>
</marquee>

<marquee scrollamount="10">
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 9</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 10</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 11</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 12</span>
</marquee>

<marquee scrollamount="8">
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 13</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 14</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 15</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 16</span>
  <span class="roundeddivs">Hello 17</span>
</marquee>

</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Normally I'd downvote any answer that dares mention `<marquee>`, but I'll admit this actually works.

Comment: @Dai Actually, after I posted the answer I was afraid that I will get down-votes for marquee.

Comment: @ChakibSalah Thanks for helping. Any way we can avoid the blank space coming in between. So eachrow is endless loop ...like Hello1Hello2Hello3Hello4Hello1Hello2Hello3Hello4

Comment: @Newbie_developer Only if you add more elements to the HTML. CSS cannot be used to duplicate elements or create elements from thin-air.

Comment: You need a couple of copies of each row to have a smooth action. marquee is deprecated and really for longevity of your site you should not be using it. CSS animations can do what you want.

Comment: @ChakibSalah super helpful. I learned the marquee concept from you. Thank you :)